# Error: while updating Database By code first EF " constraint "FK_X_Y_"z of relation "X" does not exist"

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

Issue :  constraint "FK_DestinationsLists_Regions_AirportCode" of relation "DestinationsLists" does not exist

`fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102] Failed executing DbCommand (253ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='300'] ALTER TABLE "DestinationsLists" DROP CONSTRAINT "FK_DestinationsLists_Regions_AirportCode"; Failed executing DbCommand (253ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='300'] ALTER TABLE "DestinationsLists" DROP CONSTRAINT "FK_DestinationsLists_Regions_AirportCode"; Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42704: constraint "FK_DestinationsLists_Regions_AirportCode" of relation "DestinationsLists" does not exist`

I am working a asp .net core project.
I faced this issue while updating database after add a new migration.

DestinationsList and Flights have one-to-many relationship

For Flight table - ArrivalAirportCode is the Foreign Key.

I try to add  foreginKey ArrivalAirportCode from DestinationsList table.

This is my Table.
Please help anyone to find Why this error occur?

DBContext

```
public DbSet<DestinationsList> DestinationsLists { get; set; }
public DbSet<Region> Regions { get; set; }
public DbSet<Flight> Flight { get; set; }

builder.Entity<DestinationsList>()
                .HasOne(i => i.Region)
                .WithOne(i => i.DestinationsLists)
                .HasPrincipalKey<Region>(i => i.AirportShortCode)
                .HasForeignKey<DestinationsList>(i => i.AirportCode);

builder.Entity<Flight>()
                .HasOne(x => x.ArrivalAirport)
                .WithMany(x => x.Flights)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.ArrivalAirportCode)
                .HasPrincipalKey(x => x.AirportCode);
```

```
public class DestinationsList
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
        public int Id { get; private set; }
        public string AirportCode { get; private set; }
         public Region Region { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Flight> Flights { get; set; }
   }

public class Region
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string AirportCode { get; set; }
        public string AirportShortCode { get; set; }
        public DestinationsList DestinationsLists { get; set; }
    }

 public class Flight
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ArrivalAirportCode { get; set; }
        public DestinationsList ArrivalAirport { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: Based on your code, I create a sample with the SQL server database (since I didn't have the postgresql database), after adding a new migration, the generated migration file [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUNHx.png), after that I can successfully update the database. You can check the migration file, is there any difference?

Comment: Thank you so much. Migration for create Table DestinationsList and Region is already done. Now I check those Migration files. `// migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            //     name: "FK_DestinationsLists_RegionTrees_AirportCode",
            //     table: "DestinationsLists",
            //     column: "AirportCode",
            //     principalTable: "RegionTrees",
            //     principalColumn: "AirportShortCode",
            //     onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);`   These lines are commented.